# Tracking Application Usage on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to build an iOS application that can access what other apps the user has been using over the last week or month? This would need to be done on a non jailbroken iphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your application definitely cannot access such kind of information with any public API, therefore making this impossible to achieve on a non-jailbroken phone.

Comment: Hello Gabriele, I know your answer is from 2013 and this is done right now. Any idea how? https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/in-moment-limit-phone-usage/id1171075554?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and it is already done.

Here's a link to an app, [In Moment](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/in-moment-limit-phone-usage/id1171075554?mt=8), that uses it.